# Android - Context - Google Maps V2 - Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to WindowManager

Tags: android, google-maps, android-location, android-maps-v2

I'm trying to get a WindowManager using the getSystemService() method.  Here is the code I have:

```
private int calculateZoomLevel() { 
   int ht, screenWidth; 
   DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
   WindowManager winManager;
   winManager = Context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
   winManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

   ht = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
   screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

   double equatorLength = 40075004; 
   double widthInPixels = screenWidth;
   double metersPerPixel = equatorLength / 256; 
   int zoomLevel = 1; 
   while ((metersPerPixel * widthInPixels) > 1000) { 
       metersPerPixel /= 2; 
       ++zoomLevel;
   }
   Log.i(TAG, "zoom level is: "+ zoomLevel);
   return zoomLevel;
}
```

The line that has the following code:

```
winManager = Context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
```

The error I'm getting is: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to WindowManager

Isn't this code suppose to return a type WindowManager?  How do I fix this so I can get a return type of WindowManager?

Answer (score 1):

You should simplier use `getWindowManager()` which is a method of Activity class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast it like this->

```
winManager = (WindowManager) Context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I'm wondering why you're not just using [`getCameraPosition()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#getCameraPosition%28%29) on your GoogleMap object? [The CameraPosition object has a public field called zoom](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/CameraPosition#zoom) that tells you the current zoom level.